# how to detect case change in python text and insert underscore on change location?

Tags: python, regex

For keywords such as AbcdEfgh I want to insert _ when case change happens in middle of word . So : `AbcdEfgh` gets converted to `abcd_efgh` 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what code you have so far.

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
s="AwardTitle"
re.sub(r'\B[A-Z]\B', lambda x: '_' + x.group().lower(), s)
print s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,,

```
>>> s = "abcdEfgh"
>>> re.sub(r'\B[A-Z]\B', lambda x: '_' + x.group().lower(), s)
'abcd_efgh'
>>> re.sub(r'\B[A-Z]\B', lambda x: '_' + x.group().lower(), 'AbcdEfgH')
'Abcd_efgH'
```

`\B` matches between two word chars or two non-word chars, since your input contains only word chars, the above regex `\B[A-Z]\B` must match the uppercase letter which exists at the middle. This won't touch the uppercase letter which exists at the start or at the end.

**EDIT:**

```
>>> re.sub(r'\B[A-Z]', lambda x: '_' + x.group().lower() , re.sub(r'^[A-Z]', lambda m: m.group().lower(), 'AbcdEfgh'))
'abcd_efgh'
```

Comment: Thanks . The first character is also upper . Apologies for editing it later .

Comment: You the one asked for middle character.

Comment: Thanks . It works. I was wondering how to deal with more than 2 words. E.g.AwardEffectiveDate to award_effective_date  .Current code gives return _compile error .